How to handle bulbs planted in containers in November and stored in cool garage that now have tall shoots?
I decided to create bulb "lasagna" containers this fall for early spring blooming: daylilies, crocus and grape hyacinth. I stored them in the garage but November here in the NE was extremely warm and they now have tall shoots, yellow due to no sunlight hitting them. My dilemma is, where to put these containers for the remainder of the winter? Have a screened in porch that might do. The garage seems too warm, even now that the temps have gone below freezing at night. Any suggestions? They were watered once and have grit on top, no mulch.

"The goal behind planting a bulb lasagne is to have flowers blooming throughout spring. ... You accomplish this by planting bulbs that flower at different times and are planted at different depths in a single planter."  Well that's new to me, thank you for the interesting idea.  https://lovelygreens.com/layering-bulbs-make-bulb-lasagna/

Here is a question about a similar problem, but in a garden bed instead of containers.
https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22398/newly-planted-spring-bulbs-coming-up-in-november

When you say 'here in the NE', NE of where, which country?

Aren't your bulbs hardy and don't they go in the ground?

Could you update on the area you live in. If you have mild or even moderate frosts your bulbs and daylilies should survive. You have inadvertently forced the bulbs which now need sunlight this is why they have grown as they have. Place at the side of your garage or house preferably South facing. Remember to lift pots up on bricks or something similar to allow for good drainage.
